# alert and autorefresh text box if length is 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert

I have one `text box` and i am entering data on that `text box`, what i want to do is: if i will enter `4 characters` and will `skip that text box by pressing TAB key` then one alert will come as`"data should be more than 4 characters"` and then text box will be `auto refreshed`. If data entered is more than 4 characters then no alert will come, I was trying by onkeyup event but some where i am doing wrong. Any help please

Comment: what do you mean by `auto refreshed`?

Comment: @ajax333221 auto refreshed means simply that text box will be empty again and user have to enter data again into that text box. If data entered is more than 4 characters then everything is ok but if data entered is 4 or less than 4 then alert will come as well as text box will become empty

Comment: @Sudhir i am doing wrong here and nothing is happening by my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "then text box will be auto refreshed", so I'm going to guess that you want to put the cursor back into that field. As far as checking the length of the value when tabbing out you want the `.change()` or `.blur()` event:

```
$("input[type=text]").change(function() {
    if (this.value.length <= 4) {
        alert("Please enter more than 4 characters.");
        this.focus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XHKRh/

The blur event will be triggered every time the focus leaves the field; the change event will not be triggered again if the user immediately tabs out of the field again without changing it. I prefer to use change in combination with an additional validation on form submit, so that the user doesn't keep getting pestered with alerts (though actually I wouldn't show an alert at all, I'd put the message on the page next to the field).

Comment: thanks for your answer but i found that after alert i can still proceed to the next text box, alert is coming that's fine but after alert focus ought to be kept in that text box instead moving to the next text box, i think slight edit is required in your fiddle

Comment: See my updated answer. Using `.blur()` instead of `.change()` will do what you want, but (as I said in my update) I prefer another approach.

Comment: Note also that if you use `.blur()` to force the focus back to the field the user is trying to leave then (depending on the browser) they can't switch tabs in the browser or close the browser until they type more characters and that is very annoying.

Comment: Agreed. While we have provided solutions to your problem, this is a terrible user experience. Showing a message next to the input would be preferable to this.

Answer (score 1):

How about on `blur`?

```
var el = $('#textbox').blur(function(e) {
    if (el.val().length > 4) {
        return;
    }

    el.focus();
    alert('data should be more than 4 characters');
});
```

Note that this technique makes for a poor user experience. Showing a message inline with your element would be preferable to preventing the user from interacting with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

There are some points that might result you interesting:

- You shouldn't rely ONLY on JavaScript to validate forms, as users can turn it
  off and bypass the validation
- There is a [maxlength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input) property for inputs
- You are probably looking for [onblur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onblur) instead of getting the TAB key action, since users
  can change focus in other ways

Comment: yes you are right, i should not rely on javascript only, then how can i solve this `javascript turn off` issue?

Comment: @Tom you can validate with a server-side language, (my favorite is PHP, but there are many others). But, you should use this extra measure when it is life-or-death situations where injecting  stuff would be a big problem for you

Comment: "when it is life-or-death"? You should _always_ validate in your server-side code.

Comment: @ajax333221 i cannot bind a submit button to that text box for server side checking, that's why i am using jquery, were you saying to bind a submit button for server side checking?

Comment: @nnnnnn when you are not touching the databases or similar, I think is not very necessary (although always a good idea). For example to simply redirect them to a website `http://stackoverflow.com/users/`+`<input text>`

Comment: Sure. If the text isn't being submitted to the web server at all obviously you wouldn't check it server-side, or if it isn't being stored in a DB or echoed back to the browser it probably doesn't matter, but more often than not when input elements are used the value does get stored.